# How to use pthreads for sending and receiving in a udpclient in C

Tags: c, udp, pthreads, client

I'm trying to modify a client program that my professor supplied so that it will use pthreads for the functions sendto() and recvFrom(). I was able to timetag it and have the client receive as well as send messages and have my udpserver.c echo back messages. But I can't get my pthreads to work. I'm kinda new to pthreads. This is the error I got:

```
/tmp/cciYoHsc.o:udpclient.c:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `_sendMessage'
/tmp/cciYoHsc.o:udpclient.c:(.text+0x2f2): undefined reference to `_recvMessage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think it might have something to do with all the ifdef/endif keywords. I'm not really sure what all they do. This is my program udpclient.c

/****UPDATED****/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#ifdef WIN
#include <winsock.h>
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#ifndef WIN
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
/* Here are some details of the sockaddr_in structure and the sockaddr structure
   These declarations are copied from winsock.h

   struct in_addr {       this struct holds a 32 bit IP address
        union {
                struct { u_char s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4; } S_un_b;
                struct { u_short s_w1,s_w2; } S_un_w;
                u_long S_addr;
        } S_un;
#define s_addr  S_un.S_addr

    struct sockaddr_in {   notice this structure is 16 bytes long
            short       sin_family;
            u_short     sin_port;
            struct      in_addr sin_addr;
            char        sin_zero[8];
     };
        struct sockaddr {       this generic address structure is 16 bytes long, too!
            u_short sa_family;
            char        sa_data[14];
     };

*/
/* we have to send on the same port the server is listening on */
#define PORT 20009
/* simple upd client */

//prototypes
void *sendMessage( void *ptr );
void *recvMessage( void *ptr );

typedef struct info {
    int size;
    char buffer[100];
    int nbytes,flags,addrlen;
} info;
//size = sendto(sock, (char *) buffer, nbytes,flags,(struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,(int)ptr);

int main()
{
#ifdef WIN
    SOCKET sock;
#else
    static int sock;
#endif
    static int size;
    static int nbytes, flags;
    static int i;
    static char * cp;
#ifdef WIN
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int nCode;
#endif
    static char buffer[100];
    static char str_addr[20];        /* holds the chars of an IP address */
    static struct sockaddr_in target_pc, me;

    /* magic call to initialize the network I/O code - only Microsoft requires this */
#ifdef WIN
    if((nCode = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsaData)) != 0)
    {
        printf("Opps! WSA error %d\n",nCode);
        return -1;
    }
#endif
    /* create a socket to send on */
    sock = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if(sock < 0)
    {
        printf("socket error = %d\n", sock);
        return -1;
    }
    /* we fill in the address family and port, but we do not know the destination IP address yet */
    target_pc.sin_family = PF_INET;
    target_pc.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    /* fill in my address and port */
    me.sin_family = PF_INET;
    me.sin_port = htons(0);
    me.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    i = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &me, sizeof(me));
    if( i < 0)
    {
        printf("bind result: %d\n", i);
        return -1;
    }


    nbytes = 99;

    //create threads
    pthread_t sendT;
    pthread_t recvT;

    while(1)
    {
        struct timeval te;
        struct timeval te2;

        info *sendInfo;
        info *recvInfo; 



        printf("Enter the target IP address: ");
        cp = fgets(str_addr,19,stdin);
        /* remove the \n */
        str_addr[strlen(str_addr)-1] = '\0';
        /* the inet_addr function converts a string form of IP address to a 32 binary integer */
        target_pc.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(&str_addr[0]);
        printf("Enter your message: ");
        cp = fgets(buffer,99,stdin);
        /* get the string length so we send exactly this many characters */
        nbytes = strlen(buffer);
        flags = 0;

        int addrlen = sizeof(target_pc);

        sendInfo->size = size; 
        sendInfo->buffer = buffer;
        sendInfo->nbytes = nbytes; 
        sendInfo->flags = flags; 
        sendInfo->addrlen = addrlen; 

        pthread_create( &sendT, NULL, sendMessage, (void*) addrlen);
        //size = sendto(sock, (char *) buffer, nbytes,flags,(struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,sizeof(target_pc));
        //time
        gettimeofday(&te, NULL);
        long long milliseconds = te.tv_sec*1000LL + te.tv_usec/1000; 
        printf("[Time Sent: %lld]", milliseconds);

        printf("[msg size = %d size = %d]\n", nbytes, size);


        //added


        pthread_create( &sendT, NULL, recvMessage, (void*) addrlen);
        //size = recvfrom(sock, buffer, nbytes, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,&addrlen);

        printf("Echo message: ");
        if((size > 0) && (size < 99))
        {
            buffer[size] = '\0';      //add the null byte so buffer now holds a string
            i = puts((char *) buffer);    // write this string to the display
        }
        //time
        gettimeofday(&te2, NULL); // get current time
        milliseconds = te.tv_sec*1000LL + te.tv_usec/1000; // caculate milliseconds
        printf("[Time Received: %lld]\n", milliseconds);

        pthread_join(sendT,NULL); 
        pthread_join(recvT,NULL); 

    }


#ifdef WIN
    system("PAUSE");
#endif
    return 0;
}

void *sendMessage( void *ptr ){
    //size = sendto(sock, (char *) buffer, nbytes,flags,(struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,(int)ptr);
}
void *recvMessage( void *ptr ){
    //size = recvfrom(sock, buffer, nbytes, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,(int*)ptr);
}
```

Here is udpserver.c for reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#ifdef WIN
#include <winsock.h>
#include <windows.h>
#endif
#ifndef WIN
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
#define PORT 20009
/* simple upd server 
   this program receives short messages (<99 characters) from any IP address
   and writes them to the display
   be sure to use the linker line option "-l wsock32"
*/
int main()
{
    /* first define a socket
    a socket is an I/O port like a file descriptor
    */
#ifdef WIN
      SOCKET sock;   /* SOCKET is a typedef for a structure */
#else
      int sock;
#endif
      int size;
      int nbytes, flags;
#ifdef WIN
      int addrlen;
#else
      socklen_t addrlen;
#endif
      int i;
      /* char loopback[20]="127.0.0.1"; */
#ifdef WIN
      WSADATA wsaData;              /* This is struct holds Windows required data */
      int nCode;
#endif
      char buffer[100];
      struct sockaddr_in server;    /* this holds my IP address and port info */
      struct sockaddr_in from;      /* this holds the same info for the sender of the packet
                                       I received */
      /* the call to WSAStartup is Windows magic */
#ifdef WIN
      if((nCode = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsaData)) != 0){
      printf("Opps! WSA error %d\n",nCode);
      exit;
      }
#endif
      /* create a socket called sock. It is a datagram socket */
      sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
       if(sock < 0){
       printf("socket error = %d\n", sock);
       return -1;
       }
      server.sin_family = AF_INET;   /* initialize the server address family */
      server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* notice this struct within a struct */
      /* printf("%x\n",server.sin_addr.s_addr); */
      server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
      /* associate the socket with the address structure - this is called binding */
      i = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
      if( i < 0) {
          printf("bind result: %d\n", i);
          return -1;
          } else
          printf("Simple UDP server is ready!\n\n");
      nbytes = 99; /* receive packets up to 99 bytes long */
       flags = 0;  /* must be zero or this will not work! */
      while(1){
      /* the recvfrom function is a read and the arguments are:
             sock - the socket we are reading
             buffer - array into which to read the data
             nbytes - read up to this many bytes
             flags - used for special purposes - not needed here
             from - sockaddr struct to hold the IP address and port of the sender of the packet
             addrlen - the size of the sockaddr struct written by this function
      */
         addrlen = sizeof(from);
         size = recvfrom(sock, buffer, nbytes, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&from, &addrlen);
         if((size > 0) && (size < 99)){
         buffer[size] = '\0';      /* add the null byte so buffer now holds a string */
         i = puts((char *) buffer);    /* write this string to the display */
         }

         //echo message back to client

         if(sock < 0) {//
             printf("socket error = %d\n", sock);//
             return -1;//
         }//

         sendto(sock, buffer, nbytes, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&from,addrlen); //
      }

#ifdef WIN
      system("PAUSE");
#endif
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ithink i found the problem. Im not sure, im typing and reading on a iPad.

In the end of your main function, you have placed the declaration of

```
void *sendMessage( void *ptr )
void *recvMessage( void *ptr )
```

inside of the main. Move them outside.

```
/tmp/cciYoHsc.o:udpclient.c:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `_sendMessage'
/tmp/cciYoHsc.o:udpclient.c:(.text+0x2f2): undefined reference to `_recvMessage'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I believe that this will solve the problem.

As i said, im not able to test the code myself.
Good luck

Comment: ah I think that is it. Although how would I then pass all the variables to pthread functions?

Comment: Thanks. Scotty. Marcus, as scotty mentioned, that is a bad idea. But if you realy want to do that, make the variable global.

Comment: Marcus does that mean that the original question is solved ;)

Comment: I think so I just have one more problem. I created a struct to hold all the data so I could pass to the pthread functions, but when I initialize the struct's buffer to the buffer in main it gives me a

Comment: error:udpclient.c:132: error: incompatible types in assignment

Comment: I updated it, I create a new struct called info and tried to assign some variables to the send struct

Comment: It is hard for me to get all the info from the comments like this. I think it is better to think about the problem you have, and create a new question with the new problem. I think it is for the best and it is easier for me and others to follow

Answer (score 0):

```
void *sendMessage( void *ptr ){
    size = sendto(sock, (char *) buffer, nbytes,flags,(struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,(int)ptr);
}
void *recvMessage( void *ptr ){
    size = recvfrom(sock, buffer, nbytes, flags, (struct sockaddr *)&target_pc,(int*)ptr);
}
```

you  define `size` in main then try and use it in your threaded functions, you cant do that...

Comment: whoops I got rid of the "size=" but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @MarcusLorenzana Show me how you're compiling this.

Comment: gcc udpclient.c -o udpclient

Comment: @MarcusLorenzana remove the prototypes from the top. Then move the two functions to above main.

Comment: my variables would be after the functions though